# inserting regexp_like into d2rq

Tags: semantic-web

I want to filter out only integers and FPV.

```
d2rq:sqlExpression """regexp_like(tbl1.semanticValue1,'^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+')""" ;
```

It keeps giving me **Error parsing file.**

```
illegal escape sequence value: .
```

I compared results with and without brakets:

```
[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+
```

returns: 0, -1, -1.0 , 1...

```
[-+]?[0-9][*\.]?[0-9]+
```

returns all of the above except 0

I need that zero value...

Comment: You should need to escape the `-` in the first part of your regex (in `[-+]`), but that's not what the error seems to be indicating. Do you need to escape the backslash for the string so that there's a literal backslash in your regex, which _then_ can escape the `.`?

Comment: Still doesn't fix my error...

Comment: You definitely don't want the square brackets you added in that last line of code. The asterisk is modifying the section before it. Try this: `[\\-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+`

Comment: Yea... that didn't work either: Duplicate d2rq:sqlExpression for d2rq:PropertyBridge map:semanticValue1 (E57)

Comment: What if you don't escape the hyphen (`[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+`)?

Comment: select distinct semanticValue1 
from tbl1
WHERE regexp_like(semanticValue1, '[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+'); returns nothing in sql developer. but it created triples... I just don't get it...